# How to improve the fit of a beta zero-inflated regression model (GAMLSS)?

Tags: regression, beta-distribution, zero-inflation, gamlss

I'm working with a response variable with values between 0.0 and 1.0. I have a lot of zero. Thus, I'm using beta zero-inflated regression model. Specifically, I'm using the function gamlss from the gamlss package, with family = BEZI, to test the effect of a factor (three levels) on the response variable.
With the wp function, I get the worm plot to evaluate the adjustment (following this document: http://www.gamlss.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/gamlss-manual.pdf).
However, the adjustment is not good, and it is better when I use family = BEINF (which consideres 1 values. But, my data do not show 1s).

The AIC is lower and global deviance is higher when BEZI is used, but the fit (follow worm plot) is better when I consider BEINF.

Do you know what can I do to choose the best model or how to improve the fit?
I appreciate any help you can bring me!

RESULT FOR BEZI

> m1<-gamlss(resposta ~fase, data = ciliados, family = BEZI(),trace = F);summary(m1)

---

Family:  c("BEZI", "Zero Inflated Beta")

Call:  gamlss(formula = resposta ~ fase, family = BEZI(),      data = ciliados, trace = F)

Fitting method: RS()

---

### Mu link function:  logit
Mu Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -3.3939     0.1812 -18.735 7.85e-16 ***
faseBefore    0.5548     0.2065   2.686   0.0129 *
faseFill      0.4391     0.2091   2.100   0.0464 *

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

---

### Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   6.8640     0.6332   10.84 9.93e-11 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

---

### Nu link function:  logit
Nu Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   1.5686     0.4916   3.191  0.00393 **

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

---

No. of observations in the fit:  29
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  5
Residual Deg. of Freedom:  24
at cycle:  8

Global Deviance:     -9.016796
AIC:     0.9832042
SBC:     7.819683

---

[image]

RESULT FOR BEINF

> m1<-gamlss(resposta ~fase, data = ciliados, family = BEINF(),trace = F);summary(m1)

---

Family:  c("BEINF", "Beta Inflated")

Call:  gamlss(formula = resposta ~ fase, family = BEINF(),      data = ciliados, trace = F)

Fitting method: RS()

---

### Mu link function:  logit
Mu Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -3.3938     0.1812 -18.735    2e-15 ***
faseBefore    0.5548     0.2065   2.686   0.0132 *
faseFill      0.4391     0.2091   2.100   0.0469 *

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

---

### Sigma link function:  logit
Sigma Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -3.3997     0.3268   -10.4 3.61e-10 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

---

### Nu link function:  log
Nu Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   1.5686     0.4916   3.191  0.00407 **

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

---

Tau link function:  log
Tau Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -15.27     924.26  -0.017    0.987

---

No. of observations in the fit:  29
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  6
Residual Deg. of Freedom:  23
at cycle:  6

Global Deviance:     -9.016793
AIC:     2.983207
SBC:     11.18698

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a zero inflated beta you can use BEINF0 in gamlss,
[which is a submodel of BEINF].

The reason for your different residual plots,
may be that BEZI and BEINF0 use slightly different parameterisations.

In your BEINF fit you will find that the fitted probability
that Y=1 is effectively zero, so best to use BEINF0.

Note also that you are only modelling mu in BEINF.
In BEINF0(mu,sigma,mu)
you could try including models for mu, sigma and nu.

Comment: THX, Robert. I Used BEINF0 and it improved the fit!